# Why Webmethod not firing when using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have a User Control (with Two TextBox and a label) Behind the code of the User Control On Prerender I Use RegisterStartupScript to call a JS function which calls a External JS function Which it calls a WebMethod. Everything works fine until calling the Webmethod. When calling the webmethod using AJAX. The web method does not fires up. I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

SpecificExperienceControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SpecificExperienceControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="TardyAbsenteeReport.SpecificExperienceControl" %>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnID" runat="server" />
 <div class="SpecExp">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="SpecExp-txtEmpID" ></asp:TextBox>   
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="SpecExp-txtLbl"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="SpecExp-txtAcode"></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
```

SpecificExperienceControl.ascx.vb

```
Public Class SpecificExperienceControl
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
Dim number As Int16 = 0
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub
Public Property Value As String
    Get
        Return hdnID.UniqueID
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        hdnID.Value = value
    End Set
End Property

'This function sends the necessary javascript to the page
Protected Sub Me_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender

    Dim cs = Page.ClientScript
    Dim myType = Me.GetType()

    'gets one total copy of JQuery
    If Not cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(myType, "jquery") Then
        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(myType, "jquery", GetJQueryInclude())
    End If

    'gets one total copy of the toggle function in SpecificExp.js
    If Not cs.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(myType, "helper") Then
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(myType, "helper", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/SpecificExperienceControl.js"))
    End If

    'gets one copy for each user control on the page of the js in the getStartupScript function below
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(myType, "regEvents" & Value, getStartupScript(), True)

End Sub
Private Function getStartupScript() As String
    Return "$(function(){$('#" & TextBox1.ClientID & "').change(function(){toggle('" &
        TextBox1.ClientID & "','" & Label1.ClientID & "','" & TextBox2.ClientID & "')})});"
End Function

'This function get jquery include string
Public Function GetJQueryInclude() As String
    Const CurrentJQueryVersion = "2.1.1"
    Const formatString = "<!--[if {0}><script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/{1}/jquery.min.js'></script><!{2}[endif]-->"
    Return String.Format(formatString, "lte IE 8]", "1.11.1", String.Empty) &
        String.Format(formatString, "gt IE 8]", CurrentJQueryVersion, String.Empty) &
        String.Format(formatString, "!IE]>--", CurrentJQueryVersion, "--<!")
End Function
```

End Class

SpecificExperience.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="SpecificExperience.aspx.vb" Inherits="TardyAbsenteeReport.SpecificExperience" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/SpecificExperienceControl.ascx" TagName="SpecExp" TagPrefix="HR" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <hr:SpecExp runat="server"></hr:SpecExp> 
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
 </asp:Content>
```

SpecificExperience.aspx.vb (Here I just bind the Repeater to a XML file that generates 25 empty rows)

```
Public Class SpecificExperience
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim xmldatasource2 As XmlDataSource = New XmlDataSource With
                                          {.DataFile = "/App_Data/EmptyRows.xml"}
    Repeater1.DataSource = xmldatasource2
    Repeater1.DataBind()
End Sub
End Class
```

SpecificExperienceControl.js

```
function toggle(txtId, lblname, txtcode) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SearchEmpId.asmx/GetEmployeeName",
    data: '{id: "it works"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#' + lblname).val(data.d);
    }
 });    
}
```

SearchEmpId.asmx.vb Everything works as it supposed to and then this does not get fired up

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class SearchEmpId
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetEmployeeName(ByVal id As String) As String
    Return "itworks"
    End Function
End Class
```

Below is a screen shot of what I'm getting when the request is placed

[image]

When I click in Response Body I am seeing this. Why is it not finding the web method ?

[image]

Comment: go in the developer tools under Network tab , then filter to XHR traffic ,  make sure the request is getting sent, and read the error message.  .Net framework by default send an HTML error page when something goes wrong.  You won't ever see this error though unless you look for it in the developer tools

Comment: I ran it again and in network shows the url:.../GetEmployeeName, Protocol : HTTP, method: Post, type: text/html, receive= 5.13 kb  taken 15ms initiator XMLHttpRequest. No errors on the console this time. I also change the datatype on the ajax method to "json"

Comment: ok, click on that , you need to get the response that was sent.  It looks like form your comment that the request did make it there

Comment: Hey Scott I attached the screen shot of what I am getting on the developer tool after clicking outside of the text Box . Let me know if you have any suggestions. And thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: Hey Scott it's working now. I was missing the _ after <WebMethod>. I don't know if that was it. I also erase the Shared keyword. Anyways Thanks for you help you thought me something new today. How to used the developer tool. Thanks you so much !